# Is there a programming language whose declarations are similar to those used in UML?

Tags: programming-languages, syntax, uml, esoteric-languages

Like:

```
  Employee: Person

       name: String
       id:   int


      + employeeCount(): int {
        ---------------
         return employeecount
      }
      + name():String {
           return name;
      }
      - secret():void {
           ///private method
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objective C uses `+` for class methods and `-` for instance methods -- very different interpretation, but it's the only language I know that decorates methods with plus and minus signs like that;-).

The "name: type" notation (often enriched with a leading keyword such as `var` for variables and `function` for functions) was quite popular before C took over the world, most notably perhaps in Pascal (a now-somewhat-obscure language that had a credible bid of its own for world domination not all that long ago;-).